# Add custom entry to \lstlistoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I am using the listings package for code listings.

I am using `\lstlistoflistings` to generate a list of code listings.

I have one code 'pretend' listing which is actually plain latex code, however, this comes out as verbatim text when using the `\lstinputlisting` command.

So, I would like to know how to add an entry to the `\lstlistoflistings` without using the `\lstinputlisting` environment.

Effectively -- is there an `\addtocline{}` which works with `\lstlistoflistings` ?

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{}A new listing}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{}A new listing}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

The `.lol` file is the one (corresponding to `.toc` for the ToC) which contains the information for the "List of Listings".

If you also want a number for it, use

```
\refstepcounter{lstlisting}
\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}A new listing}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

Some text that pretends to be a listings
\refstepcounter{lstlisting}
\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}A new listing}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
\addtocontents{lol}{something}
```

or

```
\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{something}
```

to add a line to the list.